# Uniform closure of an algebra $\Rightarrow$ uniformly closed algebra

Tags: analysis

In PMA, Rudin's book, there is the following theorem (7.29):

Let $B$ be the uniform closure of an algebra $A$ of bounded functions. (Here, an algebra means a family of function satisfying that it is closed under addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication.)

Then, $B$ is a uniformly closed algebra.

I ask whether the condition 'bounded' is actually the 'uniform' bounded. I think, if it means just the pointwise bounded, then we cannot show that product sequence of two sequences converges uniformly.

Do you think so?

Comment: What is bounded here is every individual function. $A$ need not be pointwise bounded, but each $f\in A$ must be bounded on all of $X$ (calling the domain of the functions $X$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is fine if $A$ is an algebra of bounded functions. In Rudin's proof of this theorem, he says it is easy to show that $f_ng_n \rightarrow fg$ where $f_n \rightarrow f$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$ uniformly. Well, you can see from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359102/16962) question that every uniformly convergent sequence of bounded functions is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thanks lot:) I appreciate your answer